# calling base class functions

Tags: c++

I have following classes.

```
class A
{

public:

void fun();

}

class B: public A
{

}

class C: public A
{

}

A * ptr = new C;
```

Is it ok to do something like below? Will i have some problems if introduce some virtual functions in the baseclass?

```
((B *)ptr)->fun();
```

This may look stupid, but i have a function that calls A's function through B and i don't want to change that.

Comment: Your example is rather ambiguous... do B and C redefine fun? Could you please post some code that actually compiles? Note for example that you should write ((B *)ptr)->fun(), otherwise you are just casting to B* the return value of the function.

Comment: What does, "I have a function that calls A's function through B", actually mean. Show us the calls? This looks like it might be a design fail.

Comment: I think you should rethink your model instead of trying to hack something like that into the code.  For example: why the code you'd like to call is implemented in B and not in A?

Comment: Dave, i am trying to reuse a messy code written by someone else. He has a  function that is taking A's pointer, but he has assumed that the function will be called with only C's instance. Now i have decided not to use his code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't cast an A* pointing to Class C as a B* because Class C doesn't have any relation with Class B.  You'll get undefined behavior which will probably be the wrong function called and stack corruption.

If you intended for class C to derive from class B then you could.  However, you wouldn't need to.  If class C doesn't have fun() defined, it will inherit A's.  You didn't declare fun() virtual though so you'll get strange behavior if you even implement C::fun() or B::fun().  You almost certainly want fun() to be declared virtual.

Comment: Actually you can cast an A* pointing to Class as a B* that's one of the beautiful/hideous things about c++. It's definitely not a good idea though.

Comment: You are correct.  It's possible, but you'll probably get stack corruption as I noted.  Maybe I should have said, "You can't *safely* cast..."

Comment: Hairsplitting really. You can write 1/0, but that still doesn't mean you can divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the casting  (B*) ptr->fun();   since the fun() is already in the base class. both objects of class B or C will invoke the same fun() function in your example.

I'm not sure what happens when u override the fun() function in class B...

But trying to invoke function from another class (not the base class) is bad OO, in my opinion.

Comment: What he has is correct because C is derived from A so the cast to (A*) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but I suspect the behavior of this might depend on the compiler you use and how it decides to organize the vf pointer table.

I'm also going to note that I think what you are doing is a bad idea and could lead to all kinds of nightmarish problems (use of things like static_cast and dynamic_cast are generally a good idea). The other thing is because fun() is defined in the base class (and it is not virtual) ptr->fun() will always call A::fun() without having to cast it to B*.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast from A * to B *, and it should work if the original pointer was B *.

```
A* p = new B;
B* q = static_cast<B*>(p); // Just work (tm)
```

But in this case it is a C *, and it is not guaranteed to work, you will end with a dangling pointer, if you are lucky you will get an access violation, if not you man end up silently corrupting your memory.

```
A* p = new C;
B* q = static_cast<B*>(p); // Owned (tm)
```